# Oracle (+) Operator with constant value

Tags: sql, oracle, outer-join

Consider below Oracle query:

```
SELECT psn_id, nvl(psn_name_lang, psn_name_kurz) psn_name, cli_code, cli_id, cli_cmp_id, p2.pat_value cli_domain
FROM tabl_psn_obj, table_cli, table_pat p1, table_pat p2
WHERE psn_id = p1.pat_psn_id
  AND p1.pat_value = to_char(cli_cmp_id)
  AND p1.pat_att_id = 3
  AND p2.pat_att_id(+) = 48 <---- what does this mean
  AND p2.pat_psn_id = psn_id
  AND p2.pat_value = i_domain
  AND cli_cmp_id = i_cmp_id;
```

I'm a lit bit confused about his `(+)` operator. As I know the `(+)` is a shortcut for `OUTER JOIN`, depending on which side you put it on, it indicates a `LEFT` or `RIGHT OUTER JOIN`.

But in the above query the left outer join is with some constant value, not with any other table ID. What does this mean? What is the similar thing in PostgreSQL?

Maybe this question could be generalized but I don't understand the meaning with a constant value.

Comment: The plus `+` indicates which side of the join is optional.

Comment: If you read the documentation on that form of outer join you will see that you must use (+) on every occurence or no occurrences of a table name or you will get an inner join. You will also find that it is deprecated & it is not a shorthand for the keyword version & you should use left or right join with keywords.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's similar to something like this:

```
select *
from t1
  left outer join p2 on t1.psn_id  = p2.psn_id and p2.pat_att_id = 48;
```

So essentially a "filtered outer join" where only a subset of the rows of the table are joined.

If the `(+)` operator was removed from `p2.pat_att_id(+) = 48` the query would become the equivalent of:

```
select *
from t1
  left outer join p2 on t1.psn_id = p2.psn_id 
where p2.pat_att_id = 48;
```

Which is something different.

---

This is another good example why the `(+)` operator should not be used any more (which even Oracle recommends).

Comment: I consider "=" as inner join, in case of "WHERE psn_id = p1.pat_psn_id", correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @NETGeek: now that you mention it. It is indeed strange to have the "outer join operator" **only** on the constant, but not on the actual join conditions. But you did convert it into an outer join as I have done in my simplified example

Comment: Just want to point out one thing and expand the explanation "..(+) operator should not be used any more (which even Oracle recommends).." - it recommends to avoid usages of this operator, cause it comes with specific rules in mind, that often people forget. But don't be afraid of it. Once you learn proper usage, it simplifies queries a lot (like for an old-dog-oracle-developer like me)

Answer (score 0):

So my final query after conversion would be like this in PostgreSQL. I consider "=" operator as the inner join. Correct me if I'm wrong

```
 SELECT k.psn_id, COALESCE(k.psn_name_lang, k.psn_name_kurz) psn_name, c.cli_code, c.cli_id, c.cli_cmp_id, ka2.pat_value cli_domain
              FROM table_krn_prs k
           inner join tbl_PERSON_atr p1 on k.psn_id = p1.pat_psn_id and p1.pat_att_id = 3
           inner join table_cli c on p1.pat_value = to_char(c.cli_cmp_id)
           left outer join tbl_PERSON_atr p2 on k.psn_id = p2.pat_psn_id and p2.pat_att_id = 48
           where p2.pat_value = i_domain and c.cli_cmp_id = i_cmp_id
```

Comment: `where p2.pat_value = i_domain` turns the outer join on p2 into an inner join. So you could just write `inner join tbl_PERSON_atr p2 ON ....` and achieve the same thing

Comment: Something like this `inner join tbl_PERSON_atr p2 on k.psn_id = p2.pat_psn_id and p2.pat_att_id = 48 and p2.pat_value = i_domain`

Comment: Adding to the comment "turns the outer join on p2 into an inner join" & my comment on the question: Find out how left join acts: it return inner join rows plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. (And your where removes any such addded rows because it removes p2 columns with null values.) PS Clarify by editing your post, not by commenting.